# Whatsapp Click to Chat with emojis

Tags: javascript, encoding, whatsapp, emoji

Using Whatsapp ['Click To Chat'](https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/chats/how-to-use-click-to-chat/?lang=en) I'm able to send a message to a number, as expected.
But, I want to send some emojis in the prefilled message. It works well when I use a browser, but it doesn't work when I use a WebView inside an app (specifically a React Native app with a webview running the same site).

**The problem**:
For both, desktop browser or webView I use the same function and same encoding (`encodeURI()`), but
when the WebView calls the Whatsapp URL ("wa.me/...") the chat on Whatsapp shows all emojis as: �

- Is it even possible to use emojis on Whatsapp Click to Chat? (I bet it is, since desktop browser works).
- What can be happening on mobile/app?
- Should I use some kind of character encoding, as unicode, UTF-8 (I already tested some, but no success)?

Here's the function that I'm using:

```js
SendWhatsapp = function(message, number) {
  number = LibGeral.NormalizeMobileNumber(number);
  if (empty(message)) {
    message = "";
  }

  var urlApiWhats = "https://wa.me/" + number + "?text=" + message;
  urlApiWhats = encodeURI(urlApiWhats);
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.setAttribute("data-action", "share/whatsapp/share")
  a.href = urlApiWhats;
  window.document.body.appendChild(a)
  a.click();
  window.document.body.removeChild(a);
  return true;
}

SendWhatsapp("I'm a message with emoji ", "xxxxxxxxx")
```

As said, inside the WebView from app, it calls the whatsapp url and opens the chat correctly, but the emoji is lost and just a question mark shows up. On Browser (Chrome, for example), it works very well and emoji appears (even on Chrome for mobile)
Also, even if I remove the encodeURI and pass the emoji 'directly', it still not working.
I'm pretty sure it was working some weeks ago...

Comment: Emojis are special characters (unicode). You just probably URL-encode those the message before adding it to the URL parameters. You can use `URLEncoder.encode()`.

Comment: @KenVanHoeylandt *"URLEncoder is not defined"*

Comment: I am facing the same issue; it has been working before, and since a couple of weeks you get this question mark, no matter how you encode it. Mobile is still working correctly, but on a computer the browser shows the question mark and also moving forward to WhatsApp application (mac/win) it is wrong.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 5):

I'm a bit late here but I ran into the same issue. Here's the solution:

Don't use

```
var urlApiWhats = "https://wa.me/" + number + "?text=" + message;
```

Use this instead

```
var urlApiWhats = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=" + number + "&text=" + message;
```

Vissie's answer is working as he/she uses `api.whatsapp.com/send/`. It's also true that the browser will still show `�` but you'll see the emoji once you open WhatsApp. However the short url `wa.me` won't work. Apprently WhatsApp's server will redirect all `wa.me` requests to `api.whatsapp.com/send/` and during that redirection emojis become `�`. It's not the problem of your code.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you should encode your URL:

```
const url = `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=31612345678&text=${encodeURIComponent('Cheers from Vissie ⚡️')};
// returns: "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=31612345678&text=Cheers%20from%20Vissie%20%E2%9A%A1%EF%B8%8F"
```

You can use `https://wa.me/`, I just used the other URL for this example. It's possible that in the browser it still gives `�`. But on your phone this should work.

Comment: Did you try? Still broken for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me either